# Set Menu for Additional Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an additional Toolbar in one of my Fragments in addition to the Toolbar that is used instead of the ActionBar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
// Other View Elements, like a profile image and name
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I want to add overflow menu for this Toolbar. These items will be specific to this Fragment and wont make sense in other Fragments.

I can access this toolbar in my Fragment with the below code.

```
mFragmentToolbar = (Toolbar) layout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
```

How to inflate a menu for this Toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inflate the menu on toolbar using this.

```
mFragmentToolbar = (Toolbar) layout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
mFragmentToolbar.inflateMenu(/*your menu resource file*/);
mFragmentToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
           return false;
     }
 });
```

Comment: This is working, Guess I overlooked that method. Thanks for the help.